# Is Azure Redis Cache used automatically for some other service. I have a charge, not sure why?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using ASP.NET 4.5, MVC 3 on Azure Websites. I do use Session Variables and some TempData variables.

I note that I am being charged for Redis Cache, not a huge amount. However, since I never set up to use it, I am puzzled. Is it used to underpin other mechanisms? I do use "inproc" session variables, and I understand that the LB will implement sticky sessions, if multiple instances exist?

I have raised a ticket for MS, but decided to ask the question here as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the Redis cache account?  It doesnt matter how much you use.  I you've created the account, you're on the hook to pay for it.

Comment: I do not remember doing it. My "Cache" items are 0. How would I check? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you didn't create an account, then raising a ticket with Billing support is the only way to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Redis Cache is supported via the new Azure portal - http://portal.azure.com
Do you see any Redis caches listed there?

Redis is not created automatically by any other service, so you should not be charged unless you manually created the cache.